# Sending over URL 2 Var (1 selected and 1 logged in user)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send over 2 vars to a page - 1 being the logged in user and the other is the ID of a registered user which is having there profile updated by the logged in user.

Im not sure how to change the page i have.

```
<?php
    include("includes/connect.php");

    //logged in users ID from logged in page.
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM guild_apply";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

?>

<blockquote>
<table border='1' width='100%'>
<tr>
    <th>ID </th>
    <th>Real Name</th>
    <th>Character Name</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
</tr>

<?php
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

 //info from all users registered with default rank (which is going to be changed)
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'];  ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['realname'];    ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['charname'];    ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['class'];       ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['rank'];            ?> </td>
    <td align="center"><a href="update.php?charname=<?php echo $row['charname']; ?>">update</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
     }
?>
</table>
</blockquote>

?>
```

------update.php-----

```
<?php

// Connect to server and select database.
include("connect.php");

$id         =$_GET['id'];
$rank       =$_POST['rank'];
$charname   =$_GET ['charname'];

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE guild_apply SET rank='$rank' WHERE charname='$charname'" or die ("cant find learner");
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ("this stuffedup");

if ($result){
    // if successfully updated. 
    header ("Location:../change.php?id=$id");
}else{
    echo "Update failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: Separate multiple parameters in a URL with `&`: `update.php?charname=x&userid=y`

Comment: But you shouldn't get login information from URL parameters, since the user can easily forge these. Use a session variable to hold the logged in user.

Comment: this might sound like a silly question but could you show an example - im home teaching myself PHP

Comment: What is the other variable you're trying to send?

Comment: the ID of the user that is logged in and the charname of the user that is being changed

Comment: yes - i have 3 different menus for each rank and its only the officer rank that can demote and premote users but atm when i select a user i can change the rank but then im stuck on their ID and not my own so my idea was sending over their charname and my ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `&id=` parameter to the URL.

```
<td align="center"><a href="update.php?charname=<?php echo $row['charname']; ?>&id=<?php echo $id; ?>">update</a></td>
```

Comment: when i enter that code i get http://localhost:8091/update.php?charname=Hellmist&id=%3C$php%20echo%20$id;%20?%3E being passed over

Comment: Typo, `<$php` should obviously be `<?php`

Comment: didnt notice that - sorry

Comment: just noticed its changing both users to the same rank instead of just the selected user